# Error while installing rapid in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to install the Rapid 7 in Linux machine. When i enter the cmd `sudo ./agent_installer.sh install_start`. It gives me the error below:

```
Installing embedded agent to --> /opt/rapid7/ir_agent
Error extracting image
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you add more details about your configuration? For example your OS can be important. Also - can you verify that your installer isn't damaged (e.g. using `md5` or `sha1` control sum)?

Comment: Ask on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My OS is Centos 6

Comment: how can i verify installer